# Convert list in list to matrix

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
list_a = [754, 753, 752]
list_b = [718, 719, 719]
```

How can I get a matrix (array) in this format:

```
array([[ 754, 718],
       [ 753, 719],
       [ 752, 719]])
```

I tried with `np.asarray` but get the wrong output.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, if `l = [[754, 718], [753, 719], [752, 719]]`

Comment: I fixed the typo. sorry for this confusion!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to transpose (`T`) the matrix (/array):

```
>>> np.array([list_a, list_b]).T
array([[754, 718],
       [753, 719],
       [752, 719]])
```